# int to chr conversion behaving differently in loop or script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have array of ints which needs to be converted into string or byte string but its behaving different when I run in script vs in  cli/repel. also same behavior when run via for loop it only encoding few of them or showing few of them.

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 19 2021, 05:27:44) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> arr = [151, 131, 104, 216, 60, 135]
>>> list(map(chr, arr))
['\x97', '\x83', 'h', 'Ø', '<', '\x87']
>>> ''.join(list(map(chr, arr)))
'\x97\x83hØ<\x87'
>>> for item in arr:
...     print(chr(item))
... 


h
Ø
<

>>>
```

Same thing i get when I print in script.
`hØ<` only

[image: int array to chr string]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `list.__str__` shows the `repr` representation of its elements, not their `str` representation. The same goes for the interactive interpreter when just displaying any expression. Hence the difference:

```
arr = [151, 131, 104, 216, 60, 135]
''.join(map(chr, arr))  # interpreter shows repr(expr)
# '\x97\x83hØ<\x87'
print(''.join(map(chr, arr)))  # print prints str(expr)
# hØ<
```

The

```
list(map(chr, arr))
# ['\x97', '\x83', 'h', 'Ø', '<', '\x87']
```

makes sense because the `repr` gives you more information of the elements. Imagine `[1, 2, 3]` vs `["1", "2", "3"]` vs `["1", "2, 3"]`. They would look identical if `list.__str__` showed the `str` representations.

Comment: got it. is there any best way to see data in its raw form specially in debugging in python.

Comment: WIth a proper debugger, you can inspect the object in real time, like calling all kinds of methods on it. For logs and prints either one should usually suffice now that you are aware of the difference. For many types, the two are also identical.